# Attempting to Install an extension to VS2019 results in a NullReferenceException

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I've not been able to add extensions to my VS 2019 since its release.
I recently updated to Version 16.4.3 but I still get the same error when I try to add extensions.

[image: Error Dialog]

I've tried to do the following but it still fails with an error dialog above.

- Install from the Extension Manager in Visual Studio;
- Download extension from MarketPlace and double-clicking to install;
- Install using VSIXInstaller.exe Commandline in VS 2019 Developer Command Prompt admin mode.

This is what I get from the install log.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.Instance.get_SupportsExtensions()
   at VSIXInstaller.SetupExtensions.GetLaunchableInstances(IQuery query)
   at VSIXInstaller.SupportedSKUs.EnumerateIsolatedInstalls(Action`1 callback)
   at VSIXInstaller.SupportedSKUs.AddInstalledLocationBasedSKUs(IntPtr userToken)
   at VSIXInstaller.SupportedSKUs.InitializeSupportedSKUs(IntPtr userToken)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.InitializeSupportedSKUs(ICommandLineData cmdLineData, IntPtr duplicatedUserToken)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

Every VS2019 extension I've tried to install so far has given me this error. Installing extensions to **VS2017** is no different.

Comment: Hi, could you please share the specific extension with us? Besides, did you face this error when you install other extensions?

Comment: l wonder if it works in the previous version of VS and did not work in VS2019.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this solution solved my problem, it is a long one, but worked for me.

[Visual Studio 2019 (Community Edition) - Cannot install/update Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242681/visual-studio-2019-community-edition-cannot-install-update-extensions)

Comment: The answer must uninstall First all VS 2017 and 2019.. Very ridiculous, how if user have installed all needed plugins but VSIX installer does not working, should them uninstall all VS 2017 and 2019 first just for fixing VSIX installer?

Comment: But that is working well. No need to download big files of VS 2019 again from internet if CC Cleaner does not remove installation files.

Answer (score 0):

l wonder if you face this issue only in **VS2019** but does work in **VS2017**.

**Besides**, you can try these steps:

**1)** delete all extension cache files under the path `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxx(the version of VS)\ComponentModelCache`

**2)** Disable any other third-party extensions and then install this extension to check whether it is caused by other extenisons.

**3)** If you cannot install this extension in VS2019 but can work in VS2017. You can try to open the installation package `xxxxp.vsix` with zip

First, open `extension.vsixmanifest` and change to this:

```
<InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[15.0,)" />
<Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0,)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
```

Second, please also change `"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor":"[15.0,16.0)"` in `catalog.json` file to [15.0,).

**In addition**, please share the info about how this issue appear and whether it works in other version of VS. And any other useful info should also be informed. If you have any errors related to this issue, please feel free to let us know.

Comment: Hi @Perry, I do face this issue with **VS2017**. I've tried with many extensions by far but still get this error. I'm beginning to think it may be caused by having both VS2017 and VS2019 installed. I feel this way because installing extensions to VS2017 worked fine until VS2019 was installed on my system. I will get one removed to see the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info. In general, VS2017 and VS2019 are installed in parallel and will not affect each other. So please check whether the installation path of vs2019 conflicts with vs2017 in vs installer.  Or you can check this in another PC. If you still face this issue, try to run `devenv /setup` in developer commnd prompt for VS2019 or do a repair in VS.

Answer (score 0):

This question references Visual Studio 2019 but we hit this just today with Visual Studio 2022. Based on the info in the log and some intuition, we have discovered that this can be caused by an exception when the vsix installer enumerates the versions of Visual Studio on the machine. I think it is either a bug in the vsix handling of older versions of VS or a misconfiguration in the supported version info of the extension itself.

In our case, this was hit on machines having a Visual Studio 2015 install. Once we uninstalled VS 2015, we were able to install the extension with no problems.